# should I dynamically create new tables for different objects?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, kotlin

I am learning to create an app where the user is able to create new subjects and store its notes(homework and stuff) with dates. I feel like I want to create a new table for each subject the user creates and manage them separately. Is it a good practice?

I have already tried creating a single table where the "ID" is basically subject name and then store the notes and date in the following columns. However, I feel that reading from the table will be time-consuming and also hard to manage. I also tried having a static table with names of the subject and then creating tables from the names stored for each subject.

Example Situation

I have created a subject - "English"
then I create a table dynamically for "English" with two columns, "notes" and "date" and then add stuff to it
Then suppose we add another subject - "Science"
then I again create a table dynamically with the name "Science" with the two columns above.

I am storing the names of these tables ("English", "Science") in a seperate table.

Here is How I am currently doing it

```
    val CREATE_SUB_NAME_TABLE = "create table " + DBStructure.TABLE_SUB_NAMES + " (" + DBStructure.KEY_SUB_NAME + " Text)"

    val DROP_TABLE_QUERY = "drop table if exists "

    private fun queryCreateSubjectTable(subName : String) : String {
        return "create table " + subName + " (" + DBStructure.KEY_EVENT_NAME + " Text, " + DBStructure.KEY_EVENT_DATE + " Text, " +
                DBStructure.KEY_EVENT_MONTH + " Text, " + DBStructure.KEY_EVENT_YEAR + " Text)"
    }

    fun addSubjectName(subName: String){
        val db = this.writableDatabase

        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(DBStructure.KEY_SUB_NAME, subName)
        db.insert(DBStructure.TABLE_SUB_NAMES, null, values)

        createSubjectTable(subName, db)

        db.close()
    }

    private fun createSubjectTable(subName : String, db : SQLiteDatabase){
        db.execSQL(queryCreateSubjectTable(subName))
    }
```

don't bother with attributes of the table... those are for testing purposes.

Comment: *"should I dynamically create new tables for different objects?"* Short answer: No bad idea  .. Long answer: No still a bad idea.

Comment: what do you mean by object table?

Comment: Also giving a real answer is a bit hard without user case or a example of the data.

Comment: *"what do you mean by object table?"* Something like? `object(id, object_type_id, date)`    `object_type( id, name (homework, "stuff"))`  maybe renaming it to something else which makes more sense to you??

Comment: Why not simply use a table `subject`, where every subject is a row?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I thought of doing that before, but then reading from the table I would have to separate each data or rather get data of each subject individually using query at run time which might cause load on the device (obviously not much but I am looking for the best way to do it).

Comment: @Serg I understand that. but can you refer the above comment I wrote where I explained why that might be a little hard to go for? Thank you

Comment: Essentially, any two "subject"s with the same set of attributes (Note, Date), the same set of relationships with other "subject"s is the same DB object, the same table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland pretty much what I was trying to explain... my bad. But what I wanted to know was is it ok if I created the object_type table during runtime?

Comment: *"But what I wanted to know was is it ok if I created the object_type table during runtime?"* Yes it can but is a bad idea.. Because your applications MySQL user needs to be more powerfull privilleges wise which can be bad for security

Comment: @RaymondNijland alright added a code of how I might add the new table. If you don't mind, can you explain to me how this might be bad for security?

Comment: well SQL injection, as that code seams to be prone to that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland so the security might be an issue with the database that is present locally right? because the app is not an online one. Also, can you please put a detailed answer so that I can mark it for others to see. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're complicating too much your problem, i mean it's ok if you want to do something like that for study puposes, but I think you can solve this using relational database as it should be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad practice. There isn't really a performance issue here.

Create a table for `Subjects` with the columns:

> Id, Subject_Name

Create a table for `Notes` with the columns:

> Id, Subject_Id (Foreign key), Note, Date

As a rule of thumb: You usually want to have one table for one type of data (model).

In this case you only have `Subjects` and and `Notes` which have a relationship to each other. The `Notes` have a foreign key reference to the `Subjects`.